# How set different users in Ansible dynamic inventory

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I want to use ansible dynamic inventory to manage AWS EC2 hosts with tag. How can I set a connection user for these hosts? My hosts are different and need to use Ubuntu user for Ubuntu hosts and ec2-user for Amazon Linux hosts.

I tried to use this dynamic inventory config and set **ansible-user = ubuntu** in **group_vars/distro_Ubuntu.yaml** but didnt help

```
plugin: aws_ec2
aws_profile: default
regions:
  - us-east-1
  - eu-central-1
filters:
  tag:Owner:
  - test
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: distro
    key: ansible_distribution
```

Comment: You're in a chicken/egg problem, `ansible_distribution` is a fact that you get from the target. To get it, you need to connect to the target and gather facts. You cannot do that if you don't have a user with credentials to connect to the target. This could eventually work if you could gather that fact from a previous run and use a fact cache. But you still need username/credentials to do that.

Comment: Post the output of `ansible-inventory --list --yaml`

Comment: The dynamic inventory should tell you what AMI the VM is built from.  Check the groups that the dynamic inventory creates.  If it's not there, you can add it to the plugin config file.